# Linker cannot find symbols in library

Tags: c++, c, cmake, linker

I built a C library using CMake. Here's the CMakeLists file for the library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(sshserial)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

include_directories(BEFORE SYSTEM ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/common/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/common/lib)

set(SOURCE_FILES sshserial.c sshserial.h)
add_library(sshserial ${SOURCE_FILES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(sshserial libssh.a)
```

I use this library in a C++ program. Here's the CMakeLists file for the program:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(sshtest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(BEFORE SYSTEM ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/common/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/common/lib)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(sshtest ${SOURCE_FILES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(sshtest libsshserial.a)
```

I have copied the library in the correct folder. When I run `nm` on the library I get this:

```
$ nm libsshserial.a 

libsshserial.a(sshserial.c.o):
                 U ___error
                 U ___stack_chk_fail
                 U ___stack_chk_guard
                 U ___stderrp
                 U ___stdinp
0000000000000330 T _create_session
                 U _exit
                 U _fgets
                 U _fprintf
                 U _free
                 U _getpass
0000000000000490 T _read_from_session
                 U _ssh_channel_close
                 U _ssh_channel_free
                 U _ssh_channel_new
                 U _ssh_channel_open_session
                 U _ssh_channel_read
                 U _ssh_channel_request_exec
                 U _ssh_channel_send_eof
                 U _ssh_connect
                 U _ssh_disconnect
                 U _ssh_free
                 U _ssh_get_error
                 U _ssh_get_hexa
                 U _ssh_get_pubkey_hash
                 U _ssh_is_server_known
                 U _ssh_new
                 U _ssh_options_set
                 U _ssh_print_hexa
                 U _ssh_userauth_password
                 U _ssh_write_knownhost
                 U _strerror
                 U _strncasecmp
0000000000000000 T _verify_knownhost
                 U _write
```

When I try to build the program, I get this linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "create_session()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "read_from_session(ssh_session_struct*)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [sshtest] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/sshtest.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/sshtest.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [sshtest] Error 2
```

I've been stuck here for some time and I am sure I'm missing something trivial. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I'm on Mac

```
$ uname -a
Darwin XXXXXX 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Tue Apr 11 16:00:51 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3248.60.11.5.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Why not make the test project a *sub-project* (in a subfolder) of the library project? Then you can do `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(sshtest sshserial)` and CMake set up the makefiles to link with the library automatically.

Comment: Also, you *do* use `extern "C"` when declaring the functions when being compiled by a C++ compiler?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : I can try that for now, and I will. But later I want to use the C library in other projects so it's not a permanent solution I guess.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : The library is built in C

Comment: Yes, and that's most likely the problem. C and C++ are different in many regards, for one C++ uses [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), to support overloading among other things. That means functions declarations of non-C++ libraries needs to be prefixed or surrounded by `extern "C"` to inhibit name mangling, since C doesn't "mangle" names.

Comment: Just please tell me, do the header file (which I assume you include in the C++ project) contain *any* `extern "C"`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : No, the header in the library doesn't (and cannot) have `extern "C"` as it's written in C itself. And if you look at the symbols indicated by the `nm` command, they are not mangled (The leading underscore is fine as far as I know).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that C++ uses [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). To inhibit that you need to declare the C functions with `extern "C"`, but only when being compiled by a C++ compiler. You can check this with the `__cplusplus` macro, which is defined when compiling C++, but not when compiling C.

In the header file where you declare the function prototypes, do something like

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
// Being compiled by a C++ compiler, inhibit name mangling
extern "C" {
#endif

// All your function prototype declarations here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}  // End of extern "C"
#endif
```

Comment: As I indicated in the comments on the post, The library is built in C so I don't need to decorate the exported symbols with `extern "C"`

Comment: @nakiya If you want to use the functions in C++, then you ***need*** it! End of story! Just *try* it.

Comment: @nakiya or, if it is a 3rd-party library, you could just bracket the `#include` with `extern "C" {..}`.